# How to deploy Servlet project to google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, maven

I create a traditional web project with Servlet, Maven and Bootstrap.

How can I deploy it to the GAE?

Comment: There is a getting started tutorial:  [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score 1):

1 Download eclippse

2 Install GAE plugin for eclipse

3 Create new project based on template

4 Create google account (gmail)

5 Create application for your google account with unique id

6 Login from eclipse to your google account

7 Deploy application to GAE using eclipse to application you create at step 5

Comment: I already have the maven project. So create new project is not so practical.

Comment: @user838204 GAE is not plain java maven or else project. It is specific. If you want to have project that will be deployed withot any gemoroy - use GAE plugin from eclipse. If you want pain - do as you think is "practical".